# Why does my js.erb doesnt work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery

I have the following code:

comment.js.erb

```
alert("Alert");
```

application.js

```
jQuery.ajaxSetup({ 
   'beforeSend': function(xhr) {xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "text/javascript")}
})

jQuery.fn.submitWithAjax = function() {
   this.submit(function() {
     $.post(this.action, $(this).serialize(), null, "script");         
     return false;
                         })
   return this;
};


$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".comment_form").submitWithAjax();
})
```

View form:

```
<% form_for :comment, :url => comment_task_path(tasks.id), 
                      :html => {:remote => true,
                      :class => "comment_form"} do |f|-%>
  <%= f.text_field :remark, :placeholder => "Add Comments", :rows => 2,
                   :class => 'box',
                   :style => "width: 834px; height: 40px;"%>
  <%= f.submit "Comment"%>
<% end -%>
```

Controller method:

```
def comment    
  @comment = Comment.new(params[:comment])
  @comment.user_id = @current_user.id
  @task.comments << @comment
  flash[:notice] = "thank you"
  if @comment.save
    # what code do I put here to render comment.js.erb?
  else

  end
end
```

What code do I need to put if I want the `comment` method to render my comment.js.erb?
I tried `render to` and `respond to`, but still it doesn't run.

Comment: Please take the time to properly indent your code. You're also not showing remotely related pieces of code. Your form is for `:update_status`, which has nothing to do with a `.comment_form`.

Comment: sorry i updated it. my mistake

Comment: In what folder is `comment.js.erb`? `app/views/tasks`? What error message do you get in development.log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to render **comment.js.erb** explicitly. By default, the controller will render the **comment.js.erb** after execution of that method. And probably you can have the following code.

in **comment** action

```
def comment
  # ...
  @comment.save
end
```

and in the **comment.js.erb** file

```
<% if @comment.valid? %>
  alert("Comment created successfully");
<% else %>
  alert("Something went wrong.");
<% end %>
```

Comment: it respond "Template is missing" but i have the comment.js.erb in the same folder.

Comment: and still i doesnt responds to comment.js.erb

Comment: Is that comment is getting created? And can you please let me know what is the error you are getting exactly?

Comment: The comment being created but then the comment.js.erb doesnt triggers. the only thing i want is to make my comment.js.erb work

Comment: once can you try rendering that template explicitely like `render 'comment'`

Comment: still it does not render the comment.js.erb

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `FORM` as argument in plugin.

```
jQuery.fn.submitWithAjax = function(elem, options, arg) {
```

Comment: i dont know but, i have included that already in my application.js

Answer (score -1):

In your routes add a get request to fetch the comments.js.erb

get 'your_controller_name/comments', :as => 'comments'

In your controller just use comments_path

Comment: Firstly, it's a post request, not a get request. Secondly, if you read the comments you would know routing is not the problem. The comment gets created.